# Why did TOSHIBA SATELLITE L755 speakers stop working?

Tags: laptop, audio, bios, speakers

The internal speakers of my laptop don't work even if they are listed on Windows Devices but if I connected headphones in the jack , the headphones only work.

No matter what driver or OS I install, these speakers won't work unless I play a music and I set my windows to hibernate then when I resume the windows, the left side of the speakers starts working but in a low volume and it stops right after 1 min.

So I wonder if this issue (of a long time ago) has something to do with the BIOS that I updated (a long time ago) especially when I go to check the system configuration in the BIOS, I see that there is no option to disable built-in speakers.

I've already replaced them in the hardware so they may not stop working for passing their life-span.

This is my BIOS:`InsydeH2O Version 03.60.453.60`.Is it linked to BIOS really? and If it is so how can I downgrade or fix this BIOS.

Here are my [system information](https://archive.org/download/systeminformation/SystemInformation.txt) and my PC [dxdiag](https://archive.org/download/systeminformation/DxDiag.txt).

Comment: Hello. You do not have an audio driver installed. Try installing your audio drivers first: https://content.us.dynabook.com/content/support/downloads/tc70148100d.exe

Comment: @NatsuKage I said no matter what driver I install this isn't solved

Comment: Then this is the common hardware issue with the L775. https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/sound-problem-on-toshiba-laptop.359192/   The Conexant chip is failing. Either mod it so it doesn't overheat, or use something external.

Comment: I gave the pc to someone and said that he needs a working chip of L775 but he didn't find it.

Comment: What is your exact computer model? ex. L775-S7130  This is usually found underneath the laptop or under the battery, on a label.

Comment: My model is L755-15R